# Adding a new string to the last line of a file

Tags: c#

Like the tittle says, I would like to add a new string on the bottom of the file, but somehow, its not working.
Hope someone can help me out x___x

```
      private string add(string asd){
        {string filename = "asd.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(filename);
        string input = null;
        while ((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            write.WriteLine(input);
        }
        reader.Close();
        write.WriteLine(asd);
        write.Close();}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356).

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

Example:

```
private string Add(string asd) {
    string filename = "asd.txt";
    File.AppendAllText(filename, asd);
}
```

Comment: +1 Great example but worth mentioning that File.AppendAllText is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing/reading from the same file at the same time. That won't work. You'll have to create a temporary file to write to.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
private string add(string asd){
{
        string filename = "asd.txt";
        string readText = File.ReadAllText(filename );
        File.WriteAllText(filename , createText + asd);
}
```